# Why can I post a comment to a question on ServerFault, but not on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, comments

Why can I post a comment to a question on ServerFault, but not on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reputation! You need 50 rep to post comments.

Reputation does not coincide between the sites. Your rep on ServerFault is independent of your rep on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't have enough rep on SO. There is a reputation requirement (50) to actually post comments on any of the sites.

It should also be noted that there is no rep requirement to post comments on questions that belong to you or answers to questions that belong to you.

Comment: Ha! I beat you with the actual number, even though you had me by 21 seconds!

Comment: You can't prove that :P

Comment: Damn you, lack of edit history.

Comment: This seems inaccurate as I cannot comment on stackoverflow (rep 20) but I can comment to this post on meta.stackoverflow (rep 18).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to comment after you have 50 rep. If you have enough rep on ServerFault, you can probably get enough on StackOverflow simply by associating your accounts.

See this for more info:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/

Comment: Thanks alot!  That really helped!